# Merging/Morphing objects and retaining old references in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Recently I was working on an interview assignment from a recruiter. The assignment involved counting players that are part of the same team. Without going into the assignment details I can state the problem.

- It is possible for each player to grow it's team.
- This requires each team member to have a reference of a common counter.
- It is also possible that two teams merge due to a common player. In that case there are two teams and two common counters.
- Now after merge it is desirable that all the players of the two teams have the reference to the same counter.

I know that one approach is to update the players of one team with others team's counter reference. But that doesn't sound optimal. Hence the question,

how two merge the two common counters?

In general sense how to design a class whose objects can be merged in such a way that their resulting object can be referenced by the exiting references?

I don't even know how to describe my requirement: morphing/merging objects? But I did it with following code. Is it a well known design pattern (like forwarding). Is there a shorter better way in Python?

```
def morph(func):
    def wrapper(obj, *args):
        morpheus = obj
        _next = getattr(obj, 'morpheus', None)
        while _next:
            morpheus = _next
            _next = getattr(_next, 'morpheus', None)

        return func(morpheus, *args)

    return wrapper


class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    @morph
    def incr(self, count=1):
        self.count += count

    @morph
    def morph_it(self, new_counter):
        if not isinstance(new_counter, Counter):
            raise TypeError("Can not morph into an object of different kind.")

        # Get effective object of this counter.
        new_counter = new_counter.get_counter()
        # Check it's not the same object.
        if self is not new_counter:
            new_counter.incr(self.count)
            setattr(self, 'morpheus', new_counter)

    @morph
    def get_count(self):
        return self.count

    @morph
    def get_counter(self):
        return self


class TestCounter(TestCase):
    def test_increment_after_morph(self):
        counter1 = Counter()
        counter2 = Counter()

        for i in range(10):
            counter1.incr()
        # Morph counter2 to counter1
        counter2.morph_it(counter1)
        self.assertEqual(counter1.get_count(), 10)
        self.assertEqual(counter2.get_count(), 10)

        counter1.incr()
        self.assertEqual(counter1.get_count(), 11)
        self.assertEqual(counter2.get_count(), 11)

        counter2.incr()
        self.assertEqual(counter1.get_count(), 12)
        self.assertEqual(counter2.get_count(), 12)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: Interesting. I was hoping for a less obscure name. But it does look suitable for my problem.